# How to store just single or just two Records/objects instead of multiple in Django Model?

Tags: python, django, database, object, django-models

I just want to store a single or may be just two objects in model but not more. And no one can add more objects in that model.How can I do that is there any option in django to use it?

Basically I just want to specify the range of objects store in models.

Thank You.

Comment: you can add condition to creating new record: `if len(model.objects.all()) > 10: don't create new ones`

Comment: you can overwrite `save()` method for that

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context about the problem you want to solve? For instance, you might want to create your schema in a way that unique constraints on fields would prevent you from adding new objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

Suppose I have people model and I want that only two records should be created then

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if People.objects.count() > 1:
            return False # or you can raise validation error
        else:
            super(People,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the save method and set a condition

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if Test.objects.count() > 1:
            raise ValidationError("You can't save more than two items")
        super(Test, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: how I can display error message on Django admin-panel working model page instead of raise validation error?

Comment: You can use django message framework.
https://medium.com/@MicroPyramid/basics-of-django-messages-framework-4315a0f3a469

but still there is lots of way